# Why are my png images displaying with a border on the iPad?

Tags: image, ipad, border

My png image looks fine on my website's homepage in IE, however on the iPad, there is a TOP, LEFT and bottom border displaying. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a link on your image ? If yes try adding this to your CSS file :

```
a img{
    border-style:none;
}
```

That will hide the border.